# Excel remove row with invalid email

Tags: excel, delete-row, email-validation

I have a large contact spreadsheet, with the columns Name, Phone, Email etc...
In which there are so many rows with invalid email so I would like to remove rows which contain invalid email, any suggestions?

Comment: Write some VBA code. If you are going to delete the rows then start at the bottom and work up.

Comment: you know any VBA snippets? please provide...

Comment: ok np, I just fixed the issue with the help of some php code, I will add it to answer section, I know that's not the exact answer but that helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to write a user defined function to validate if the cell contains a valid e-mail adress (TRUE) or not (FALSE) using the RegExp55 libraries of VBA.

You can start using this code:

```
Option Explicit

Const MODULE_NAME As String = "modMail"

'' Validate email address
Public Function ValidateEmailAddress(ByVal strEmailAddress As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Catch

    Dim objRegExp As New RegExp
    Dim blnIsValidEmail As Boolean

    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.Pattern = "^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$"

    blnIsValidEmail = objRegExp.Test(strEmailAddress)
    ValidateEmailAddress = blnIsValidEmail

    Exit Function

Catch:
    ValidateEmailAddress = False
    MsgBox "Module: " & MODULE_NAME & " - ValidateEmailAddress function" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
        & "Error#:  " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End Function
```

which I took from this [tutorial](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/validate-email-vba.html). If you look at the link you can find a description of how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the code, look like your code can validate emails but I am looking for deleting rows if it contains invalid emails in the Email column, I just created some php codes its working fine to me, it can work with bulk list nicely... but have to use php platform to run, any way I will add those code in answer section....

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution, it's working perfectly with my large list, this is not the exact answer, need a PHP platform to run.

**Input_List.csv**

Name | Email | Phone

**Here is my code for above table:**

```
<?php 
    $input_file = "Input_List.csv"; //source file
    $output_file = "Output_List.csv"; //cleaned output file
    $fp1 = fopen($input_file, "r"); 
    $fp2 = fopen($output_file, 'w'); 
    if ($fp1) {
        while (($lines = fgetcsv($fp1)) !== false) {
            //print_r($lines);
            $inv_flag = 1; 
            $cf_x_c_d = ''; 
            $co = 0; //incrimenting tocken for column
            foreach ($lines as $cf_x) {
                if($co == 1){ //check if 2nd column, 2nd column is the email column
                    if(validate_email($cf_x)){
                        $cf_x_c_d .= $cf_x.",";
                    }else{
                        $inv_flag = 0;
                    }
                }elseif($inv_flag == 1){
                    $cf_x_c_d .= $cf_x.",";
                }
                $co = $co + 1;

            }   
            if($inv_flag == 1){
                $cf_x_c_d_arr = explode(',', $cf_x_c_d);
                fputcsv($fp2, array_values($cf_x_c_d_arr));
            }
        }

        fclose($fp1);
        fclose($fp2);
    }   

    function validate_email($email){
        $email = str_replace(' ', '', $email);
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

  ?>
```